# remove the n smallest elements from a vector, including repeating elements

Tags: r, sorting, rank

I have the following vector:

```
v = c(1,2,3,1,3,2,3,4,3,3,1, 5, 5,2)
```

I would like to obtain the vector

```
v_new = c(3,3,2,3,4,3,3,5,2,2)
```

from which I removed the first smallest elements which are 1, 1, 1, 2. Please not that I do not want to remove the other occurrence of the number 2. The function `order` almost gives me what I need, except its output is weird because it takes care that v[order(v)] gives the elements in increasing order and does not give the rank of the elements. `rank` also gives something strange:

```
v[rank(v)]
 [1] 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 5 3 3 2 5 5 3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is what you need, but to make it work, you need negative indexing. By itself, `order` returns the set of indices that would sort the input vector:

```r
v = c(1,2,3,1,3,2,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,2)

order(v)
#>  [1]  1  4 11  2  6 14  3  5  7  9 10  8 12 13

v[order(v)]
#>  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 5
```

You can use negative indexing to remove elements from a vector:

```r
(5:1)[c(-1, -2)]
#> [1] 3 2 1
```

Putting the two together, to remove the smallest elements from a vector, negate the first n elements of the results of `order`:

```r
v[-order(v)[1:4]]
#>  [1] 3 3 2 3 4 3 3 5 5 2
```

Note that `order` indexes tied elements from the front, which is why the first 2 is the one removed.